# DataGridView Missing Rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-3.5

I'm trying to add some rows to a DataGridView.

After I get past the 12th row it stops displaying.

When I break in via the debugger, I can see that my DGV has all the rows. They just don't get displayed.

I've tried doing the equivalent of giving it a swift kick (moving focus around, moving the selection to the last item, Application.DoEvents() and so on, but to no avail).

```
OtherButton.Focus();
MoveFocusToNext();
_policyDataGrid.Focus();
_policyDataGrid.Rows[_policyDataGrid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Selected = true;
Application.DoEvents();
_policyDataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = true;
Application.DoEvents();
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

NB: I've seen a lot of posts where the DataGridView has a binding source, but this one doesn't. It's got a lot of manual Rows.Add().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
_policyDataGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
_policyDataGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
```

But there's an Rpc wait in there in my app, so this might not be real time enough for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CurrentCell property:

```
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
```

This is with the AllowUserToAddRows property set to false.

Comment: Almost there ... the new rows appear and it shows up at the bottom of my DGV, but then if I click the scroll bar it jumps back to the top and I can't scroll past row 6 or so. Going to try resetting scroll bars ...

Comment: @micahhoover You must have an event somewhere interfering with things.  Obviously, you do have to get rid of those Application.DoEvents calls changing focus and in your posted question you are always "selected" the first row again.